# How to make responsive layout with floated list-items?

Tags: css, list, width, css-position

I'm making a responsive list with floated `<li>`'s, where I want the list to stay with three columns. However, when resizing the window the floated items are pushed – as with fixed items – into two columns, instead of resizing. Here's an example of my code:

```css
#list {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

#list li {
  position: relative;
  width: 27%;
  float: left;
  margin: 2% 2% 0 0;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li>item1</li>
  <li>item1</li>
  <li>item1</li>
  <li>item1</li>
  <li>item1</li>
  <li>item1</li>
<ul>
```

Comment: i dont really see how your codes would push it down. (27+2)*3=87. It doenst exceed 100. http://jsfiddle.net/RAjML/

Comment: Ah I see, I had a 2% padding that screwed things up ;) cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem with % and maring/padding in N-column layouts is **pixels rounding**.

If you define 2%+2%+2% padding, without rounding it could be `20.4px+20.4px+20.4px=61.2px`. But with rounding it will give `20px+20px+20px=60px`.

Also different browsers may round pixels differently. Suppose that 2% is equal to 20.7px. Some browsers may round it to 20px, others to 21px.

---

You can use **inner element** if you need to combine % and some margin/padding. Is is best what I've found so far for cross-browser solution:

HTML:

```
   <ul id="list">
       <li><span>item1</span></li>
       <li><span>item1</span></li>
       <li><span>item1</span></li>
       <li><span>item1</span></li>
    <ul>
```

css:

```
#list{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

#list li {
    width: 33.3%; /* nice 3 columns */
    float: left;
    padding: 0; /* should have zero paddng/margin */
    margin: 0;
}

#list li > span {
 margin: 6% 6% 0 0; /* now margins are specified relative to outer <li> width */
 display: block;
}
```

Aditionally you can specify two columns for lower screen sizes:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
   #list li {
        width: 49.9%;
   }
}
```